# RxJava2 action not executed if user leaves screen

Tags: rx-java2

I do a remove action through RxJava2 that causes a refresh on my local cache like this:

```
override fun removeExperience(experienceId: String, placeId: String): Completable {
    return from(placesApi.deleteExperience(experienceId, placeId))
        .andThen(from(refreshPlace(placeId))
            .flatMapCompletable { Completable.complete() }
        )
    }
```

so whenever the remove action is done (`Completable` is complete), a refresh is triggered. The problem is, sometimes this remove action takes long enough for users to just leave the screen, and then the `andThen` action is never executed cause there is no subscribers anymore, and thus the information on the screen is not up to date anymore.

Is there a way to enforce this action to take place?

Comment: can you try moving the operation to be performed by a component that is bound to the application's lifecycle (rather than the screen)?

Comment: like a service? what other component would work?

Comment: it really depends on your app's architecture. it could be a service. it could be the `Application` instance (or some other member that it delegates to). the key point is you wouldn't be dependent on the viability of the `Activity`/`Fragment` instance. if you're able to share more about the layout/design i might be able to offer more concrete recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Does this logic continue working when user open the same screen again? If so, then you only need to finish subscription `from(placesApi.deleteExperience(experienceId, placeId))` on lifecycle events. The easiest way is to add the whole subscription `removeExperience()` to Disposable or CompositeDisposable and then trigger its `.dispose()` or `.clear()` on view stop or destroy events.

- `.dispose()` - doesn't allow to use the same subscription stored.
- `.clear()` - allows re-subscription without creating the new
  subscription instance